# In Linq, how to find if a set contains an element without using Count(predicate)?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, optimization, exists

Since `IEnumerable.Contains()` method does not accept a predicate as an argument, Most people use the following code to check the existence of something matching a condition:

```
// ProductId is unique.
if (Products.Count(c => c.ProductId = 1234) == 1)
{
    // Products list contains product 1234.
}
```

This code forces to walk through *every product* and to check if it matches. There is really no need to do so.

When looking at Linq-to-SQL generated SQL code, there is the same problem. A `select count(*) ... where ProductId = @p0` statement is sent, instead of `if exists`.

How is it possible through Linq to find if a set contains an item which matches a condition, without having to walk through every element in a set and count the number of matches?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try

```
if (Products.Any(c => c.ProductId = 1234))
{
//do stuff
}
```

Not sure if that uses an if exists, but you can try and see what is sent.

Comment: It works. Sql query is `select (case when exists(...) then 1 else 0 end)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to check a condition you can use the following code

```
if(Products.Any(p => p.ProductID == 1234))
{
    //do sth
}
```

but if you want to check if any rows exist without any condition like p.ProductID == 1234 you should do the following

```
if(Products.Any(p => p != null))
{
//do sth
}
```